# Another salt-dough question

Tags: everyday-chemistry

In January 2017, someone asked how salt dough worked.

[How does salt dough work?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/how-does-salt-dough-work).

In the answer it was said that the salt gives toughness.  My question is would the size of the salt crystals matter. Kosher table or ground to a powder?  This has relevance to a craft project.

Comment: I'd say doesn't make a big difference, but the processability might be worse with fine powder. Why don't you try it out?